# react-native-storage returning undefined from local storage

Tags: react-native

I am having some difficulties on executing local storage operations...

```
"react-native": "0.64",
"react-native-storage": "^1.0.1"
```

I'm using react-native-storage, as pointed in title, and I have created two simple methods for handling Writing and Reading:

```
import Storage from 'react-native-storage';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const storage = new Storage({
  size: 1000,
  storageBackend: AsyncStorage,
  defaultExpires: null,
  enableCache: true,
  sync: {
    return: 'No data.'
  }
});

const saveToLocalStorage = (key: any, data: any) => {
  storage.save({
    key,
    data,
    expires: null
  })
}

const getFromLocalStorage = (key: any) => {
  storage.load({
    key,
    autoSync: true
  })
    .then(data => {
      return { data }
    })
    .catch(err => { });
}

export { saveToLocalStorage, getFromLocalStorage }
```

As you can see, it's pretty much the code example from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions.

At the App.tsx file, I do the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    saveToLocalStorage('test', 'test data');
    const test = getFromLocalStorage('test');
  }, [])
```

which returns `undefined`.

But if in the method `getFromLocalStorage` I replace

```
.then(data => {
      return { data }
    })
```

for

```
.then(data => console.warn(data));
```

the result is the image from bellow:

[image: Can't believe this happens]

In short:

- If the function returns the object from the storage, it brings undefined.
- If the function returns a console.log from the storage, it brings what I've written on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `return { data }` is not a valid expression for async functions

just use `AsyncStorage`, `react-native-storage` is not needed unless you develop for both mobile and web

```
useEffect(() => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('test', 'myValue');
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('test');
    console.log(value);
  }, [])
```

Comment: I decided to use react-native-storage because RN said AsyncStorage is deprecated, as following: https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage ; but using '@react-native-community/async-storage' is actually from community hahahaha, thanks bro